# apple push notification server

Tags: apple-push-notifications

How can I verify that if I have established a successful connection with apple push notification service with my apns provider. I am sending device token to server and I am not able to send it to my device.

Comment: use delegate method:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
    NSLog(@"Registration successful, bundle identifier: %@, mode: %@, device token: %@",
          [NSBundle.mainBundle bundleIdentifier], [self modeString], token);
}

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the status of the ssl connexion. What language do you use?